# Custom Indexing Python Data Structure

Tags: python

I have a class that wraps around python `deque` from `collections`. When I go and create a deque `x=deque()`, and I want to reference the first variable....

```
In[78]: x[0]
Out[78]: 0
```

My question is how can use the `[]` for referencing in the following example wrapper

```
class deque_wrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_structure = deque()

    def newCustomAddon(x):
        return len(self.data_structure)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data_structure)
```

Ie, continuing from above example:

```
In[75]: x[0]
Out[76]: TypeError: 'deque_wrapper' object does not support indexing
```

I want to customize my own referencing, is that possible?

Comment: Instead of asking [a separate question for each method needed to emulate a `deque`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716437/custom-python-data-structure), you should skim the [Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) section of the docs (that you've now been given links to in both questions). Almost everything you're likely to ask for is going to be there.

Comment: Also see [`collections.abc.MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html). If you inherit from that, and implement the give methods listed in the table, it'll automatically give you all the other methods that `deque`, `list`, and similar types have. (If you're in Python 2.x, it's called `collections.MutableSequence`, no `abc`… but if you're in 2.x, you shouldn't be declaring a class with no bases like this, as someone else explained on your previous question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to implement the [`__getitem__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__):

```
class DequeWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_structure = deque()

    def newCustomAddon(x):
        return len(self.data_structure)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data_structure)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # etc
```

Whenever you do `my_obj[x]`, Python will actually call `my_obj.__getitem__(x)`.

You may also want to consider implementing the [`__setitem__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__), if applicable. (When you write `my_obj[x] = y`, Python will actually run `my_obj.__setitem__(x, y)`.

The documentation on [Python data models](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) will contain more information on which methods you need to implement in order to make custom data structures in Python.

Comment: If you're going to implement `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, unless you've got an explicitly-fixed-size collection, you probably also want `__delitem__` (and probably `insert` and `append` and so on, too).